# php Issue with Intro.js using it in a foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade, intro.js

I have decided to use Intro.js to create a guide for my website.

But I have this issue. If I put Intro.js in a loop it works for all the rows it generate. so each loop generate 50 rows dynamically from result from DB and hence generate 50 intro.js.

Is there way to `break;` or `stop` Intro.js not go through the entire loop and focus on one row instead?

```
@foreach($providers as $key => $provider)
    <tr data-intro="{{ TL::helpdesk('viewvilkareachrowdescription') . $provider->name }}"></tr>
@endforeach
```

Hope its possible? please help anyone?

Comment: try to use an if statement inside the foreach

Comment: I hope an exampel would be real great

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use an if statement to do something on only one row and print the others.

**here is an example :**

```
  @foreach($providers as $key => $provider)

        @if ($provider->name == 'any_name')
             ... // << case focus on one row 
        @else
             <tr data-intro="{{ TL::helpdesk('viewvilkareachrowdescription') . $provider->name }}"></tr>
        @endif

    @endforeach
```

and here is a link to documentation about Blade Templating : https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates

Comment: That was so easy, why I did not think of it. thank you